# MailApp with Variables

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send emails from a google sheet, The code below works:

```
MailApp.sendEmail
    ({
       name: "me",
       to: "firstEmail@mail.com", 
       cc: "secondEmail@mail.com",     
       subject: subject1,
       htmlBody: "<p>THIS IS THE TEXT</p>"
    });
```

but `MailApp.sendEmail` doesn't work with the variables, the code below sends emails only to the emails in quotation marks but not the variables

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) 
  {
   var row = data[i];
   var email1 = row[2]; //This range has an email address
   var email2 = row[3]; //This range has the another email address
   var subject1 = "this is the subject:"
   
   MailApp.sendEmail
    ({
       name: "me",
       to: "thisOneWorks@mail.com", email1, 
       cc: "thisoneAlsoworks@mail.com", email2,     
       subject: subject1,
       htmlBody: "<p>THIS IS THE TEXT</p>"
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({name: "me",to: `thisOneWorks@mail.com, ${email1}`,cc: `thisoneAlsoworks@mail.com, ${email2}`,subject: subject1,htmlBody: "<p>THIS IS THE TEXT</p>"});
```